# Is any work around available for making Chrome sort correctly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, sorting, angularjs-orderby

I used AngularJS orderBY for sorting an array in my application. The array is sorted correctly in all browsers except for the Google Chrome (which is really surprising for me, given the vast audience Chrome have). This link here makes it clear that Chrome V8 do have this glitch. [V8 sorting defect](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=90)

I want to know what does orderBy do internally? Reading Angular docs do not help much. Can this be a issue with Angular orderBY code?

Mainly, Is there any way Chrome sort can be made to work properly? I am hoping there must be a way, as I am reluctant to believe Chrome has this issue.

Unlike many other question posted on orderBy, i am not having a code issue (quotes issue an all) because all other browser show perfect result.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651220

Comment: @BalajiM i have tried this, it had no effect as such. In fact, now I am doing the thing like:

`$scope.sortorder='code';`

and in html I have 

`ng-repeat=" x in items | orderBy: sortorder"`

This works perfect iN IE11, only Chrome seems to have issues

Answer (score 1):

Note: This observation applies to pure JavaScript sorting rather than orderBy in Angular.

I wanted to clarify this problem because I have been facing this issue for months and the reason why it occurs came to me in a dream, literally.  When IE and Mozilla sort, where two elements match, the existing order is maintained.  When Chrome sorts if two or more elements match, the resulting order is NOT maintained.  This means if you sort an array on one key, then sort it again on another key, the results of the first sort are LOST.

The link above "V8 sorting defect" provides a solution in comment 4.  The solution is to always sort in a single pass and in your sort function have a hierarchy of if statements for handling what to do when elements are equal.  And truthfully, that is more efficient than multi-pass sorting.

Marlin